# jquery как получить второй элемент

Tags: jquery

на странице есть 2 дива с классами slider-track . Как в jquery получить второй div с классом slider-track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом **[.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

Только учтите, что нумерация там начинается с нуля, поэтому в метод вы передадите не номер 2, а 1:

```js
let $secondElement = $('.slider-track').eq(1);
console.log($secondElement.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-track">1 элемент</div>
<div class="slider-track">2 элемент</div>
<div class="slider-track">3 элемент</div>
```

---

Ещё можно так же, но чуть по-другому))) **[:eq() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

```js
let $secondElement = $('.slider-track:eq(1)');
console.log($secondElement.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-track">1 элемент</div>
<div class="slider-track">2 элемент</div>
<div class="slider-track">3 элемент</div>
```

---

Ещё вариант **[:nth-child() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)**

```js
let $secondElement = $('.wrapper .slider-track:nth-child(2)');
console.log($secondElement.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-track">1 элемент</div>
    <div class="slider-track">2 элемент</div>
    <div class="slider-track">3 элемент</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавлю только, что с версии `3.4+` `:eq()` как селектор является устаревшим.